# Convert dropdown of exposed sorting of view into Checkboxes

Tags: views

I have created view in that view I exposed **sorting** with dropdown field 'Distance', 'Rating', 'Review', it works fine. Now I want to convert that dropdown into checkboxes with AJAX callback.
I used module  [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) please suggest me to how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this goal by Implementing [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

e.g:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name == 'test' && $form_state['view']->current_display == 'page_1') {
       // do your alteration stuff
       $form['sort_order']['#type'] = 'radios';
        //$form['sort_by']['#type'] = 'radios';
    }else
    if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name == 'test' && $form_state['view']->current_display == 'page_2') {
       // do your alteration stuff 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes its working for me. Now I am trying to get that radios into checkboxes. for that I have to enable multi selection on sorting after that I will get checkboxes. thanks for ur efforts.

Comment: Hi @Kailash if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I Suppose this may help you using [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters)

Comment: Thanks for your timely response. But as I mentioned above I am searching for "SORTING" and not a filtering.